# Populate list items from custom plugin php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I want to edit a custom function to display a list instead of displaying a list after a dropdown item is selected.

Here is my code:

```
    function listings_content($attr){
  ob_start();
  ?>


    <label for="state">Select A State:</label>
    <select id="napb_listing-state-select" onchange="location.href = '?state='+this.value">
      <option value=""></option>
      <? foreach(napb_listing::states() as $abr => $name): ?>
      <option value="<?=$abr?>" <?=$_GET['state']==$abr?'selected':''?>><?=$name?></option>
      <? endforeach; ?>
    </select>

  <?
  if($_GET['state']){
    $listings = napb_listing::findByState($_GET['state']);
  }else{
    $listings = array();//napb_listing::find();
  }
  ?>


    <? if(!$_GET['state']): ?>
    Select a state
    <? elseif(count($listings)==0): ?>
    No listings at this time
    <? endif; ?>

  <?
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $content;
}
```

here is the sample page http://blacksquidsolutions.com/test/

Answer (score 0):

if i'm understanding correctly you want the list to drop down as if the user has already clicked it? 
if that's the case try this bit of javascript:

`document.getElementById('napb_listing-state-select').click();`

Will give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: I want to remove the dropdown and just have the list populate when the user lands on the page.

Comment: Look at your first block of code, you're rendering it as a `select` with `options`. Not sure how you want it to display, but if you change it to something like 
`<div>
      <? foreach(napb_listing::states() as $abr => $name): ?>
            <span value="<?=$abr?>"<?=$name?></span>
      <? endforeach; ?>
</div>`
You should see it just dump on the screen

Comment: Thanks acaputo, but I just want to list all items. looking for something like <? php echo = $listings ?> My php is very rusting. :(